# Using await inside a forkjoin TS

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous

I am trying to retrieve a new result based on an old result. So when a particular parameter in my dominant call is X it should call another function, but my current problem is that the scope continues its run, which causes the new parameter to be lost.

The code looks as:

```
export class DashboardGuard implements CanActivate { 


 public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> { 
    this.logger.info(DashboardGuard::canActivate());
    return Observable.create((subscribe: Subscriber<boolean>): void => { 


    Observable.forkJoin(
                this.mapSettingsService.fetch(),
                this.userSettingsService.fetch(),
                this.mapFenceService.fetch(),
                this.markersMotesService.fetch(),
                this.markersStaticsService.fetch()
            ).subscribe((result: [MapSettings, UserSettings, MapFenceGroup[], MarkersMotes, MarkersStatics]): void => {

                // Fetch loaded motes and statics
                const mapSettings: MapSettings = result[0];
                const userSettings: UserSettings = result[1];
                const mapFenceGroups: MapFenceGroup[] = result[2];
                let markersMotes: MarkersMotes = result[3];
                const markerStatics: MarkersStatics = result[4];

                for (let i in markersMotes.items) {
                    if (markersMotes.items[i].longitude === 0 || markersMotes.items[i].latitude === 0) {
                        // Here I want to call another fetch with the data from the previous fetches, but the program scope
                        // should wait until it finished those fetches.
                        //  Example of fetch:
                        Observable.forkJoin(
                            this.markersMotesService.newfetch(markersMotes.items[i].macAddress),
                        ).subscribe((result: [MarkersNolocations]): void => {
                            const newResult: MarkersNolocations = result[0];
                            if (newResult.missedCounter > 0) {
                                markersMotes.items[i].latitude = 10;
                                markersMotes.items[i].longitude = 10;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
})
```

I get that the forkjoin is an awesome option for retrieving all calls, but what about calls inside that?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Greetings,

Bram

Comment: Why you are you using forkJoin a second time? You are only using result[0]. Does newFetch return multiple Observables?

Comment: It doesnt make any sense :), I am editing this project but new to Angular, more a react kind of guy. Cheers for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

Nested subscriptions should generally be avoided. Chaining operators is preferred. In this case you want to use switch map to pipe the output of one observable into the input of another.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

I modifed your code to use switchMap, to give you an idea. I don't know what your MarkerMotes class looks like so doubt it works as is but it should give you an idea.

```
let itemsNeedingLocation: SomeClassHere[] = [];
Observable.forkJoin(
                this.mapSettingsService.fetch(),
                this.userSettingsService.fetch(),
                this.mapFenceService.fetch(),
                this.markersMotesService.fetch(),
                this.markersStaticsService.fetch()
            ).switchMap((result: [MapSettings, UserSettings, MapFenceGroup[], MarkersMotes, MarkersStatics]): void => {

                // Fetch loaded motes and statics
                const mapSettings: MapSettings = result[0];
                const userSettings: UserSettings = result[1];
                const mapFenceGroups: MapFenceGroup[] = result[2];
                let markersMotes: MarkersMotes = result[3];
                const markerStatics: MarkersStatics = result[4];
                let obs: Observable[] = [];

                for (let i in markersMotes.items) {
                    if (markersMotes.items[i].longitude === 0 || markersMotes.items[i].latitude === 0) {
                        itemsNeedingLocation.push(markersMotes.items[i]);
                        obs.push(this.markersMotesService.newfetch(markersMotes.items[i].macAddress));
                    }
                }
                return Observable.forkJoin(obs);
            }).subscribe((result: [MarkersNolocations]): void => {
                itemsNeedingLocation.forEach((item, index) => {
                    if (result[index].missedCounter > 0) {
                        item.latitude = 10;
                        item.longitude = 10;
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Cheers for your response, for clarification I editted so you can see my entire scope. The current problem witch switchmap is that it doesnt work on my observable cause its an subscriber I think? Not sure where it breaks (kind of new to these kind of practices).

Comment: The basic idea is that the output of forkJoin goes into switchMap and then the output of switch map goes into subscribe

Comment: The problem is that I cant change the subscribne method with switchmap, with the notion that it doesnt exist on type Observable